# how???subseting,conditioning, consecutive conditions, dataframe conditions on factor(binary) column(vector in r language)

Tags: r, subset, markov-chains, markov

i have a sequence of 1/0's indicating if patient is in remission or not,

assume the records of remission or not were taken at discrete times,

how can  i check the markov property for each patient, then summarize the findings, that is the assumption that the probability of remission for any patient at any time depends only if the patient had remission the last time/not remission last time(same as thing as saying probability of remission for any patient at any time depends only if the patient had remission in the previous row, well if not first observation)

P(r=1 at t=t+1|r=1 at t)=p(r=1 at t+1|r=1 at t, r=0 at t=t-1, r=1 at t=t-2, r=1 at t=t-3)

easy to understand if you understand the markov property

this is an exercept of my df

patientId   remission

```
ju67       1

ju67       0

ju67       0

ju88       1

ju88       1

ju23       1

ju23       0
```

any ideas? subsetting the dataframe with the required condtions then computing probabilities using 'msm' package or (probably better way) just viewing the state transitions table will work but how do i do this, for the subsets of dataframe i would need for example to include only patients with three consecutive 0's in remission(including 0 in remission now) and compare this to subset of a dataframe with two consecutive 0's in remission(including 0 in remission now) –

question was asked, but this statement has parts that really help i believe

Comment: Posting a duplicate of a question with a garbled mathematical expression of the Markov property is continued evidence that you need to be putting more effort into understanding you own homework.

Comment: lol the expression is very clear in my eyes,  and especially to a mathematiccian/statistician eyes i don't understand what the issue with the expression is,also i am new to this forum and the question is not a duplicate because before i didn't talk about subsetting which is more of an r programming thing, before i was more in the direction of probabilities

Comment: do have any idea how to do this?

Comment: Tabulating a shifted vector within a category doesn't seem that difficult. Why don't you address the issues that have been raised?